# куда и как устанавливать gradle в android studio?

Tags: android, gradle, apk

выдаёт ошибку sync failed.
наверно я удалил скачанный самой IDE gradle. потом скачал с градлского сайта градл отдельно. указал путь к градлу. но все равно немогу сделать сборку пустого проекта.
android studio version 3.1.2.
gradle version 4.4.

Вот что пишет в логе:
Gradle sync failed: Connection reset
            Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (11s 831ms)

помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: град сам по себе если что качается сам если ему чего-то не хватает

Comment: вообще то это грэдл вам и пишет, что синхронизация "провалена" соединение сброшено, а не то, что вы думаете. то есть, сам он есть и работает, но соединиться с сервером не может

Comment: вах, дело и в том-то, что не может качать. Толи интернет плохой, толи блокируют. я прошу условно брата тот качает и отправляет по почте. работаю в оффлайне почти. есть ли возможность установить готовый градл чтобы тот без интернета сборку делал?